# How can I handle multiple kinds of Lists in the same method?

Tags: java

I currently have methods with these signatures:

`public static List<Integer> keep(List<Integer> input, Predicate<Integer> p)`

`public static List<String> keep(List<String> input, Predicate<String> p)`

`public static List<List<Integer>> keep(List<List<Integer>> input, Predicate<List<Integer>> p)`

The all do the same thing. How can I handle any of these three kinds of Lists in a single method? I have already tried using the wildcard (`?`) operator, but when I do this I get an error about there being no way to add a `CAP#1` Object to a List.

Here is an example of one of the methods:

```
public static List<?> keep(List<?> input, Predicate<?> p) {
    List<?> keepList = new ArrayList<>();

    input.stream().filter((i) -> (p.test(i))).forEach((i) -> {
        keepList.add(i);
    });

    return keepList;
}
```

In this method, keepList.add(i) generates an error that says:

> no suitable method found for add(CAP#1)
>
> method Collection.add(CAP#2) is not applicable
>         (argument mismatch; Object cannot be converted to CAP#2)
>
> method List.add(CAP#2) is not applicable
>         (argument mismatch; Object cannot be converted to CAP#2)
>
> where CAP#1,CAP#2 are fresh type-variables:
>       CAP#1 extends Object from capture of ?
>
> CAP#2 extends Object from capture of ?

Comment: It would help to see that error, and the code that generated it, and also to know what the method does. Telling us that they all do the same thing don't tell us what they actually do. Post some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a generic method.

```
public static <T> List<T> method(List<T> list) {
    ...
}
```

You can restrict `T` the same way you do with classes if you need to; eg `T extends Number` or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, based purely on the type signature, you can use generics for this. Define a type parameter  for the method and use it as the type of each of the lists/predicate.

```
public static <X> List<X> keep(List<X> input, Predicate<X> p)
```

Considering how `java.util.function.Predicate` works and the name of your method `keep`, this is likely enough to make your code generic and reduce 3 functions to one function.